# What does the ACARS Weight and Balance Request page look like?

Tags: airline-operations, airbus-a320, weight-and-balance, fms, acars

In the ATSU AOC Preflight menu of an Airbus (maybe Boeing too), there is an option for a weight and balance request. The selection name varies by airline but it may say "W/B Req" "Send LoadSheet" "LoadSheet REQ & Confirm" "Weight Manifest Request" "Loadsheet Request" "Load Data Report" or "W/T Balance".

What does this page look like? What information does the pilot have to enter in this page?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it will vary by airline. Mine has a few screens, and the pilots enter in number adults and children in each seating zone, number of total infants, number of standard and heavy items in cargo, any additional weight in cargo (shipping cargo, mail, ballast, etc). Also the desired runways to get data for and their condition (dry, wet, snow, etc).

Many, sometimes all, of these items are auto-populated when the gate agent closes the flight, except for the desired runways.

When the response is received, it contains weights and center of gravity numbers, and then each runway will have specific thrust (temperature, ECS/bleeds, flex, and target resulting thrust) and flap settings, as well as the V speeds.

Comment: "When the response is received, it contains weights and center of gravity numbers," Doesn't this already come from the loadsheet that is delivered via ACARS after loading is complete? Is the pilot filling the weight and balance request after receiving that final loadsheet?

Comment: Varies by airline, my answer is mostly specific to mine. We don't get a distinct load sheet through ACARS. Our takeoff data request is automatically populated with passenger and baggage/cargo counts, and then we send for the takeoff data. This calculates everything and sends a takeoff report back to us that includes everything my answer outlines.